# Storing filepath as variable in python

Tags: python, variables, ubuntu, filepath

I'm sure this is an easy question but I have searched for a while to no avail. I want to define a file path as a variable and use that variable elsewhere in my python code on Ubuntu. What I have so far is:

```
filefolder = '/home/Desktop/Sample Loading'
```

and I call on it later in the code as:

```
file = open('%f/EventLog.txt' % (filefolder), "a")
```

When I do this, I get an error saying that a float was expected and not a string. How can I get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `%f` is the format code for `float`. Just because it's the initial for `file` doesn't mean Python can redefine the standard format string syntax to accommodate that. Read the docs for [`printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `file = open('%s/EventLog.txt' % (filefolder), "a")` with %s instead of %f

But you are much better off using `os.path.join(filefolder, 'EventLog.txt')`

Comment: Oh, I'm assuming it's because %f means float?

Answer (score 2):

You passed a formatter that expected a float (%f) not a string (%s).

You can either replace this with `%s/Event log.txt` or just concatenate it directly like so, `filefolder + '/Event log.txt`.

Do note that you're  better off working with `os` module directly for essentially anything to do with paths :-)

Will edit answer if you require further explanation as II sent this from phone.